# Open source alternative for borland developer studio

Tags: c++, c++builder

Is there any open source alternative for Borland developer studio 2006?

I need this because, I have a c++ project with developer studio project (bdsproj) files(OLD one), 
I need to do a reverse engineering 'kind of' stuff.

OR any other way to accomplish this. Like (Converting bdsproj to c++ Proj(visual studio projects ))

Your thoughts/comments are highly appreciated.

-Raja

Answer (score 5):

C++ builder uses Borland components. It's called VCL - Visual Component Library. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Component_Library

An OpenSource alternative to that is LCL - Lazarus Component Library.

I think this is the best you can get: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_%28software%29#Lazarus_Component_Library

Hopefully it's not limited to Free Pascal. I think there is a special trick to call these components from C++. It works the same as Delphi components being called by C++ builder.

In the future, it should work without any tricks. http://www.freepascal.org/future.html

Here is more info: http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=80.0

Comment: It is limited to Pascal, unfortunately.  Lazarus is the IDE for the FreePascal open source compiler.  This would be a solution if you were working with Borland Delphi projects, not Borland C++ projects.

Comment: Thanks @Remy Lebeau, i have also tried with lazarus. It is their future concern to include C++ language too. Let us wait.

Comment: @marek, thank you. i have tried it already. But i will also look for tricks to use correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Not for the C++ portion of the Studio, no.  For the Delphi portion, there is the [FreePascal](http://freepascal.org) compiler and the [Lazarus](http://lazarus.freepascal.org) IDE.